# Anyone using IronPython in a production application?

Tags: ironpython

I've been toying with the idea of adding IronPython for extending a scientific application I support.

Is this a good or horrible idea?

Are there any good examples of IronPython being used in a production application.  I've seen Resolver, which is kind of cute.  Are there any other apps out there?

What I don't get is this.  Is it any easier to use IronPython than to just use something like code DOM to create script like extensibility in your application?

Anyone have some horror stories or tales of glorious success with IronPython / IronRuby?

Comment: I guess silence, in its own way, is a response to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm at Resolver Systems, so I was lurking to see if anyone replied :-)

In answer to your question...

- I think [Autocad has IronPython and IronRuby built in](http://au.autodesk.com/?nd=class&session_id=5125)
- [The IronPython cookbook](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Main_Page) references a dating site and an online gambling site as using IronPython in production, which sounds dubious (the site is a wiki, so I'd suspect spam) but the links were added by someone using the site's owner's login, so who knows...

Comment: Thanks Giles.  Resolver and Autocad both seem like a good place for this type of extensibility.  Why did you guys pursue the use of IronPython instead of VSA, for instance?  Was this a language preference, or licensing issue?

Comment: Hi Scott,

It was a language preference, mostly.  We saw VB almost as one of the problems we were helping our clients to escape from by moving from "other spreadsheets" to Resolver One -- so we decided to make Resolver One scriptable in either Python or Ruby.  We needed tight integration with .NET, and IronRuby didn't exist yet, whereas for Python there was both Python.NET and IronPython -- so we evaluated both and wound up going for Python.


Giles

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing web development for a German firm using Django on the server side and Silverlight with IronPython on the client. We're an all Python development company so being able to do "full stack" development with Python is great (although it was originally the customer who specified Silverlight).

Answer (score 2):

Success Story:

[ANSYS Inc.](http://www.ansys.com/) is an engineering simulation software (computer-aided engineering, or CAE) organization. [Ansys Workbench scripting](http://www1.ansys.com/customer/content/documentation/121/wb2_js.pdf) is based on IronPython 2.6.